# Can I import data from one hosted database to another hosted database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases that I connect to remotely via SSMS, which are both hosted on GoDaddy's servers, but not on the same server.

I would like to run a script against the two databases that extracts some data from db1 and then imports the data to db2.

**Is there anyway I can do this, or would I be better of writing a small program that can access both SQL connections and run the scripts from there?**

The data in db2 will only hold the value of a couple columns from one of the db1 tables.

Comment: It might not be what you're looking for, so I don't want to add it as an answer, but I've had a lot of success using Red Gate's SQL Data Compare for exactly this situation (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/). It let's you move data between databases and transform columns if the schema doesn't exactly match. It's a little pricy, but there's a free trial available on the site.

Comment: @mfanto Thanks. I'll take a look at that. This is the first time I've ran into this situation, and I'm hoping that it's an isolated deal.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you said they are on different servers. Do a select * from sys.servers and see if the other server is listed as a linked server. If it is, you should be able to tell if you can access it.

Comment: @anAgent I cannot. This is the whole issue. I had tried that, but I wanted to check and see if someone much craftier than I had come up with a work around.

Comment: @anAgent When I run "select * from sys.servers.dbo.db1.MyTable", I get this error: "The object name 'sys.servers.dbo.db1.MyTable' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3." Any idea?

Comment: The query "select * from sys.servers" will only list the linked servers (accessible servers). To access another server, the command would be "select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]. Can you move the database so they are on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well usually you can export/import data using your SSMS through the DTS (Import/Export Wizzard). The wizzard is accessed when rightclicking on the database node and selecting Tasks->import or Tasks->export

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't need the entire db1, just a couple columns of data from one of it's tables.

Comment: Then you will provide a simple query. You may transfer a whole database or use a query to extract specific portions.